# Странные COM DLL

Tags: c++, qt, 1с, activex

Появилась задача прицепить к программе на с++/qt драйверы торгового оборудования для 1с8.3. Казалось бы проблем быть не должно т.к. технология внешних компонент 1С документирована [очень хорошо](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:3221:hdoc:_struct_folder), как и [требования к драйверам](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:4829:hdoc) (хотя это совершенно не важно).
С native компонентами проблем не возникло - там все однозначно и прямолинейно.

А вот с COM какой то бардак! Для примера я взял драйверы для ККМ из поставки 1С8.3. Они поставляются в zip архивах в виде dll/so и файлов manifest.xml и info.xml. Проблема в том, что все библиотеки, созданные по технологии COM разные! Только одна dll соответствует спецификации! Остальные реализуют расширения языка 1С как попало, но тем не менее, каким то волшебным образом, в 1С они все прекрасно работают. Я подозреваю это происходит потому, что 1С это очень древняя платформа и внешние компоненты COM пишут как попало, а 1С вынуждена весь этот зоопарк поддерживать. В принципе реализовать все костыли, применяемые 1С можно без особого труда, но выяснилась очень неприятная вещь - некоторые DLL с COM объектами не содержат в себе манифеста с описанием интерфейсов COM.

Например Spark115FComp.dll это компонента, созданная по всем правилам - в ней 4 интерфейса, 3 и которых требует технология. Это единственная COM библиотека, сделанная по стандарту.

Библиотека smDrvFR1CLib20.dll реализует 2 интерфейса - один для ДТО 2.0, а второй для ДТО 2.2. Интерфейсов которые должны быть по технологии нет. В требованиях ДТО это вроде допустимо.

Библиотека IskraKKTLib.dll (AddIn.IskraKKT) вообще за гранью добра и зла! Я не могу сгенерировать TLB для этой компоненты. OleView выдет ошибку "LoadTypeLib(\IskraKKTLib.dll) failed. Error loading type library/DLL. TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY ($80029C4A)". Получить ITypeInfo прямо из программа тоже не могу - получаю пустой указатель.

```
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
ax = new QAxObject("AddIn.IskraKKT");

ITypeInfo *typeInfo = nullptr;
IDispatch *dispatch = nullptr;
ax->queryInterface(IID_IDispatch, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&dispatch));
if (dispatch){
    dispatch->GetTypeInfo(0, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &typeInfo);
}
```

В компоненте просто нет информации ни о доступных интерфейсах ни о доступных методах. Я в тупике. Предположим, что все COM-драйверы возвращают интерфейс по умолчанию, реализующий нужные функции. Тогда как мне вызывать функции этого интерфейса? На сколько я понял dynamicCall использует ITypeInfo для вызова произвольной функции, поэтому использовать его не получится. Значит нужно сгенерировать описание интерфейса. Но как это сделать?
Буду очень благодарен за помощь.
На всякий случай прилагаю dll с COM драйверами. https://yadi.sk/d/AGhuibb-UbVYpQ

Comment: Попробовал использовать интерфейсы, описанные в addin.idl, входящем в комплект разработки расширений 1С. В нем описано несколько интерфейсов (IInitDone, IPropertyProfile, IAsyncEvent, ILocale, ILanguageExtender, IStatusLine, IExtWndsSupport, IMsgBox, IPlatformInfo),но ни один из них получить не удалось.

Comment: IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames не находит ни одну функцию в IskraKKTLib.dll, но находит все в smDrvFR1CLib20.dll. Вот такие COM-драйверы бессмысленные и беспощадные.

Answer (score 0):

Одним из вариантов решения может быть подключение обычной dll (не для 1С) см http://www.iskra-cto.ru/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8/

Comment: Тогда мне придется самому писать реализацию требований к ДТО 1с8.3 и самому отлаживать. В идеале софтина должна брать ДТО для 1с8.3, подключать к себе и выставлять его функции в сеть. С другой стороны может быть любая программа, которая умеет HTTP. Выбраны драйверы для 1С8.3 т.к. это готовое, законченное и хорошо документированное решение, которое поддерживается если не всеми то большинством производителей и позволит подключать любое торговое оборудование по сети к любой программе. Драйвер AddIn.IskraKKT не один такой. Например еще 3 драйвера ККТ из поставки 1С ведет себя также.